# Free functor from $Set$ to $Set^*$

Tags: category-theory

I would like to find a left adjoint functor to forgetful functor $U:Set^* \rightarrow Set$. I think it must be ,,free'' functor $F:Set \rightarrow Set^*$, but I have problem to construct this and I can't find it in books and Internet. Could anyone give me a hint? I would be very grateful.
PS:Is there also a right adjoint?

Comment: Is what you denote as $Set^*$ the pointed category, having as objects pairs $(X,x)$ where $X$ is a set and $x\in X$?

Comment: Yes, I denote $Set^*$ as pointed sets.

Comment: To complete drhab's question : are the morphisms of $\mathbf{Set}^*$ the functions such that $f(x)=y$?

Comment: Yes, morphism are like you say.

Comment: As pointed sets is a variety of universal algebra (e.g. like groups and rings), the free functor is *left* adjoint to the forgetful functor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick a set $s$. We want to construct a functor $F\colon \mathrm{Set}\rightarrow\mathrm{Set}^\ast$ such that for all pointed sets $(t,t_0)$ the isomorphism
$$\hom_{\mathrm{Set}^\ast}(F(s),t)\cong \hom_{\mathrm{Set}}(s,U(t))$$
holds. Denoting by $\mathrm{pt}$ the terminal object in $\mathrm{Set}$, consider the construction
$$F(s):=(s\sqcup \mathrm{pt},\mathrm{pt})$$
(where I denote by $\mathrm{pt}$ both the one-point set and the unique element it contains).
Now the above isomorphism is given by
$$f\mapsto f\vert_s$$
with inverse 
$$g\mapsto g\sqcup[\mathrm{pt}\mapsto t_0].$$

I'll let you check by yourself that this construction is natural in $s$ and $t$.

Edit: This proves that $U$ admits a *left* adjoint $F$ (which was asked for at the time this answer was created). As for a right adjoint, see Kevin's answer.

Comment: The OP asked for a right adjoint to $U$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson At the time this answer was posted, the question was about a left adjoint, though.

Comment: Got it, I didn't notice the edit.

Comment: Nice. Under acceptance of axiom of foundation (so that $X\notin X$) you could also go for $F(X)=\langle X\cup\{X\},X\rangle$.

Answer (score 4):

$U$ admits no right adjoint, as it does not preserve colimits. For instance, the coproduct of pointed sets is the so-called wedge product, $(S,s)\vee (T,t)=S\sqcup T/(s\sim t)$, which does not map to the disjoint union under $U$.